# submit a form via Ajax using prototype and update a result div

Tags: javascript, ajax, prototypejs, form-submit

I'm wondering how can I submit a form via Ajax (using prototype framework) and display the server response in a "result" div.
The html looks like this :

```
<form id="myForm" action="/getResults">
    [...]
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
<div id="result"></div>
```

I tried to attach a javascript function (which uses Ajax.Updater) to "onsubmit" (on the form) and "onclick" (on the input) but the form is still "non-Ajax" submitted after the function ends (so the whole page is replaced by the results).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Check out Prototype API's pages on [`Form.Request`](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/form/request) and [`Event`](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/event) handling.

Basically, if you have this:

```
<form id='myForm'>
.... fields ....
<input type='submit' value='Go'>
</form>
<div id='result'></div>
```

Your js would be, more or less:

```
Event.observe('myForm', 'submit', function(event) {
    $('myForm').request({
        onFailure: function() { .... },
        onSuccess: function(t) {
            $('result').update(t.responseText);
        }
    });
    Event.stop(event); // stop the form from submitting
});
```

Comment: I thinks this answer is better than the selected answer because this way you do everything in the javascript side. There is no adding onsubmit="return myfunc()" to the form

Comment: Couldn't agree more separation is vital!

Comment: N.B. -- prototype is not compatible with file uploads submission through Ajax. See http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/136931 .

Comment: another note -- you might want to call Event.stop() first, in case you encounter an exception.

Comment: This worked for me. Although since I am a total Javascript newbie, it took me some time to realize that in order for this to work. The javascript has to appear after the form in my source or after the items have been created dynamically.

Answer (score 3):

You need to return the value false from the ajax function, which blocks the standard form submit.

```
<form id="myForm" onsubmit="return myfunc()" action="/getResults">


function myfunc(){
   ... do prototype ajax stuff...
  return false;
```

}

Using onsubmit on the form also captures users who submit with the enter key.

Comment: I did the "return false" in the function but I was missing the return above the function in onsubmit...

Answer (score 3):

You first need to [serialize your form](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/form/serialize), then call an [Ajax Updater](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/ajax/updater), using [POST options](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/ajax/options) and pass it the serialized form data. The result will then appear in the element you sepcified.

Comment: The way that @Paolo said it already serializes our form and send it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop the default action of the `onsubmit` event.

For example:

```
function submit_handler(e){
    Event.stop(e)
}
```

More info on [stopping default event behavior in Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/event/stop) »