# Remote form with A tag submit in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a remote form with hand-made buttons using  tags. I'm using data-remote=true in the form tag, but I don't know how to use the link tag to post the form data in a form submit. When I use data-remote with data-method, it creates a remote call with empty parameters, so I don't call the submit() function to my form.

My form is:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/tasks" data-remote="true" method="post">
```

and my link tag under the form tags are:

it creates a remote call with empty POST parameters:

```
<a class='minibutton' data-remote='create' href='/tasks/create' data-method='post'>
```

it doesn't send any POST information, only the header:

```
<a class='minibutton' data-remote='create' href='/tasks/create'>
```

How can I call elegant the submit() method of the form? I guess I don't need to create javascript hacks to make it work. Do I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess there're 2 ways you can solve it:

1.
I see you're using a class called 'minibutton' on your link, which suggests you want it to look like a button anyway. So instead of the link (or `<input type="submit">` tag), use the button tag inside your form:

```
<button type="submit" value="Submit">
```

and style it to your liking using CSS. You can even use icons on them. Check out [this blog post](http://particletree.com/features/rediscovering-the-button-element/) for details and a ready to use chunk of CSS code.

2.
If you still want to use the link, you can set "id" attributes on the link and on the form, and add a click event observer to submit the form.
Assuming you're using Prototype, put something like this into the head part of the page:

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>
    $('YOUR-LINK-ID').observe(
        'click', 
        function(el, value) {
          $('YOUR-FORM-ID').request({
            onSuccess: function(response) {eval(response)}
          })
        }
    );
<% end %>
```

This is assuming your response content type is text/javascript. If it's not, you'd have to use the onSuccess and/or onComplete callbacks to replace a piece of your page with the response contents.

See documentation on [Form.request](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/form/request/) and [Event.observe](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/event/observe/) for details on observing and submitting a form.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443276/submit-a-form-via-ajax-using-prototype-and-update-a-result-div) may also be helpful.

Comment: Thanks your reply, currently I'm observing the onclick signal and make a submit() when the click event occurs. Your first solution sounds good and better because I don't need the handle that case when a search robot tries to check the link. My problem with buttons was the customization in IE and Safari, but as I look it works well. thx!