# how can i get file data on ajax page in magento?

Tags: magento

I have made a custom module in magento. I am using ajax in it(prototype.js).i can find the post variable on ajax page. But I am unable to find the file array on ajax page.
I am using following code for this.Please let me know where i am wrong?

```
//Ajax code on phtml page
new Ajax.Request(
    reloadurl,
    {
        method: 'post',
        parameters: $('use-credit-Form').serialize(),
        onComplete: function(data)
        {
             alert(data.responseText);
        }
    });
//Php code on ajaxpage
public function ajaxAction()
{
    $fileData   =   $_FILES;
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($fileData);die;
}
```

It always print blank. but when I added this line 
"VarienForm.prototype.submit.bind(usecreditForm)();"
I can get the value of file array. but draw back now page starts refreshing.

Please give me some suggestion.

Comment: What does your HTML look like? Does it work without AJAX?

Comment: yes it is working fine without ajax

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Event.observe('use-credit-Form', 'submit', function (event) {
    $('use-credit-Form').request({
        onFailure: function () {
            alert('fail.');
        },
        onSuccess: function (data) {
            alert(data.responseText);
        }
    });
    Event.stop(event); // stop the form from submitting
});
```

Credit: [submit a form via Ajax using prototype and update a result div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443276/submit-a-form-via-ajax-using-prototype-and-update-a-result-div)

Comment: I try this but still problem is same.Still there is no file data.When I print $_File. it prints blank always.